# Two ribbon with same z, they covered each other

Tags: webgl, three.js

I'm drawing map roads with THREE.Ribbon, every road has border with different color, so I use two ribbons, one is wider with the color of border, one is narrower, then I can achieve my purpose.

I also draw cap on two ends of ribbon with circles, certainly draw two circles, the smaller one covers bigger one, just like linecap in canvas2D.

I can't use THREE.Line as my alternative, because the maximum value of width of Line is 1 in my webgl.

My codes are just like this:

```
var circleShape = new THREE.Shape();
var circleRadius = lineWidth/2;
circleShape.moveTo( 0, circleRadius );
circleShape.quadraticCurveTo( circleRadius, circleRadius, circleRadius, 0 );
circleShape.quadraticCurveTo( circleRadius, -circleRadius, 0, -circleRadius );
circleShape.quadraticCurveTo( -circleRadius, -circleRadius, -circleRadius, 0 );
circleShape.quadraticCurveTo( -circleRadius, circleRadius, 0, circleRadius );
var circle = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( circleShape);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: color, depthWrite: false} );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( circle, material );
this.parent.add( mesh );

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: widerColor, depthWrite: false} );
var widerRibbon = new THREE.Ribbon( widerGeometry, material );
this.parent.add( widerRibbon );

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: narrowerColor, depthWrite: false} );
var narrowerRibbon = new THREE.Ribbon( narrowerGeometry, material );
this.parent.add( narrowerRibbon );
```

My logic is the latter will cover the former. so narrower ribbon will cover wider ribbon, ribbon will cover half of circle.

My difficulty:

The consequence is they cover each other(without depthWrite:false).

I have found that THREE.MeshBasicMaterial can set depthWrite to false, I add it, then I find that narrower ribbon covered wider ribbon successfully, but what is weird is the cap on the ends of ribbon seems abnormal, when I look at the ribbon right on top, it works well, but when I look it with a angle, I find that the ribbon can't cover circle.

I don't know how to deal this issue, I just want the later drawing covers the former drawing when they all have same z coordinate.

Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "painter's algorith" (whatevr is painted last is always what you see), just turn Z off in the material(s). This is, set the "depthTest" attribute to false when declaring the material

Comment: I know the "depthTest" you mentioned, I have set it to false, but the phenomenon is same with "depthWrite:false".

      this.camera.position.z = 1500;

      this.camera.position.z = 1000;
      this.camera.position.y = -600;
      this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

Comment: I know the "depthTest" you mentioned, I have set it to false, but the phenomenon is same with "depthWrite:false".

When I set camera position like this:
      this.camera.position.z = 1500;
It works well,
But when I set position like this:
      this.camera.position.z = 1000;
      this.camera.position.y = -600;
      this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

The cirles on the top half is displayed, it should be covered by the ribbons, the bottom half works well.